# Laravel Auth::attemp() not working

Tags: php, api, laravel-5

I'm trying to get my `Auth::attemp();` to work. But it keeps returning false;

This is my api login:

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
         if(Auth::attempt($request->parameters[0]))
         {
             dd('true');
         }
         else {
             dd('false');
         }
    }
```

When I make a post request with postman:

```
{"parameters":[
    {"email":"test@gmail.com","password":"testtest"}
]}
```

It returns false while the credentials are right (checked that multiple times)

I've changed the user model to employee. And put it in a other directory. I've changed that in `App\config\auth.php`

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\src\employee\Employee::class,
        ],
```

What should I do? Did I forgot something?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are sending array type to attempt

```
 if(Auth::attempt($request->parameters[0]))
```

Try with this

```
 if(Auth::attempt(["email"=>"test@gmail.com","password"=>"testtest"])
```

If still not work then try with default providers

```
 'model' => App\User::class,
```

Comment: Still not working -_- But when I change it back to 'model' => App\User::class, I've to call my class user that's not what I want.